# difference between integral arc sinh x and arc sin x

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

this is very basic. 
i saw some people proof that inverse hyperbolic function for $\sin x$ is
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sinh^{-1}x)={1\over \sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
but if i use triangle
$$y=\sin^{-1}x$$
$$x=\sin y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}={1\over {\cos y}}$$
why i get
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^{-1}x)={1\over \sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

which one is true?
is arc $\sin x$ and $\sin^{-1}x$ different thing?

Comment: Your title says inverse hyperbolic sin, but no hyperbolic functions apper in the post.  Perhaps you mean $\frac{dy}{dx}(\sinh^{-1}x)={1\over \sqrt{(1+x^2)}}$?

Comment: To add, yes, $\text{arcsin}x$ and $\sin^{-1}x$ are indeed two notations for the same function

Comment: @sharding4 yes!! i mean that, is it different from $\frac{dy}{dx}(sin^{-1}x)={1\over \sqrt{(1-x^2)}}$?

Comment: Yes.  $\sin^{-1} x$ and $\sinh^{-1} x$ are different functions, although they do satisfy very similar algebraic relations.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}(sin^{-1}x)={1\over \sqrt{(1-x^2)}}$ this is the same as arcsin x and $\frac{dy}{dx}(\sinh^{-1}x)={1\over \sqrt{(1+x^2)}}$ is hyperbolic? so thats why it is written in sinh(?)

Comment: Yes.  The "Pythagorean identity" for the hyperbolic functions is $\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2 x =1$ accounting for the sign change.

Comment: @DevinaMuljono , if you wish someone to be notified that you have replied to a comment they made, start your message (as I did) with an @ sign and the first three letters of their username. Sometimes they will get notified, it seems to be random chance if you don't use the @ sign

Comment: @sharding4 if i use hat identity can i find the derivative of sinh using triangle?

Comment: @WillJagy thankyou! will get used to it!!

Comment: You wouldn't use a triangle, but otherwise yes the hyperbolic pythagorean identity follows the steps you outlined in your post.  You'll get $\cosh^2 y = 1+x^2$ rather than $\cos^2 y = 1-x^2$ in the case of the circular functions.

Comment: By the way, $\frac{dy}{dx}(\sin^{-1}x)$ is **NOT** the derivative of the function $\sin^{-1}x$. Instead, this notation means the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of some mysterious unknown function $y(x)$ multiplied by the function $\sin^{-1}x$. Taking the derivative of $\sin^{-1}x$ is written as $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^{-1}x)$ (using this notation).

Comment: @sharding4 should i change sinh x to $ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$? or can ou give me more hint? thanks! and sin x and sinh x is two different world(?)

Comment: @zipirovich ah yes sorry for typo!! i edited my post!!

Comment: And for hyperbolic functions the formula is $\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1$...

Comment: You really should update the title or the question so they match. The title is about hyperbolic functions, while the actual question is about trigonometric functions.

Comment: @skyking oh i got it... just insert  $\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1$ this into the $\frac{dy}{dx}={1\over {\cos y}}$thanks!!!!!!

Comment: @DevinaMuljono But do you mean $\sinh$ in all cases where you write $\sin$? If that's the case you should update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not confuse  $\quad
\frac{d}{dx}(\sinh^{-1}x)={1\over \sqrt{1+x^2}} \quad
\text{with} \quad
\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^{-1}x)={1\over \sqrt{1-x^2}}$

They are typos in what you wrote (corrected below) :

[image]

Comment: thankyou really appreciate for the correction!!! ^^ so sin x and sinh x have two different rule? and we use he rule according the question(?)

Comment: The rule of derivation is the same for $\sin^{-1} x$ and $\sinh^{-1} x$. But the results are different. The result of the same rule is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ for the first and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$  for the second.  This is not surprising since two different functions have two different derivatives.

Comment: okay thankyou so much for the explanation!!